# High CPU usage from "NT Kernel & System"

Tags: windows

Not sure what is going on.  I have ran Process Explorer and I dont' see any of the usual culprits.  I have consistent 70-90% CPU usage.  It's often within the services process due to Windows Update. I typically just disable the windows update service and I'm good to go.  But over the last couple days, ntoskrnl.exe has been chewing away at my performance big time.

My computer starts slowing down more and more and more, and eventually practically comes to a halt.  Oddly enough, sometimes it will slow down to a grind even though the CPU usage only says it is at 50%.  A couple months ago I upgraded the RAM to 16GB, which seemed to help but now it seems whatever issue I am dealing with has finally caught back up.

I don't see anything particularly insightful to me within process explorer, and none of the help articles I googled are helpful.  Any tips?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: have you captured and analyzed the trace? have you found the cause?

Answer (score 3):

To diag the CPU usage issues, you should use Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) to capture CPU Sampling data / Profile.

To capture the data, [install the Windows Performance Toolkit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), which is part of the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

[image]

Now run `WPRUI.exe`, select `First Level`, under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**.

[image]

Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**.

Now [analyze the generated ETL file with the Windows Performance Analyzer](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) by drag & drop the `CPU Usage (sampled)` graph to the `analysis pane` and order the colums like you see in the picture:

[image]

Inside WPA, [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx) and expand Stack of the SYSTEM process. In this demo, the CPU usage comes from the nVIDIA driver.

Comment: Nice info, but do I really need all 6 gigs of the Windows Assesment and Deployment toolkit, and I already have the Windows 10 SDK installed with Visual Studio 2017 CE.

Comment: @Gala you don't nee all other entries only the WPT, which his 100MB. Depending on what you selected in VS2017 you may already have it installed.

Comment: You are a life saver! My X220 was running 95C+ all day today, and turns out it was a dodgy Ricoh SD/MMC driver.

Thanks!

Comment: @Gala can you please share the picture of WPA.exe which shows that so that I can add it to my answer to also help other users?

Comment: @Gala ok, I already saw this issue and analyzed it on sysinternals.com. I've added a screenshot in my larger answer in the duplicate topic.

Comment: Of course, here it is: http://i.imgur.com/YyCs4iq.png

As you can see, the `risdxc64.sys` module is causing over 50% of the load on the CPU, and that file is part of the Ricoh SD/MMC card reader driver.

Comment: And also, highlight that in newer versions of WPA, you need to switch to the "Stack" view here: http://i.imgur.com/EmqFbye.png

Comment: @Gala thanks, but I already remembered a case and pasted the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSWLI.png

Comment: Turns out its a known issue on XX20/XX30 series thinkpads and their card readers. Bummer.

Comment: @Gala thanks for this information. if you still need a SD card reader, buy an external USB based on which uses a different chip (realtek)